# Macro error "Autofill Method of Range Class Failed" in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to run the below script in a macro and it keeps giving me this error "Autofill Method of Range Class Failed." Any advice please?

```
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer

WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
For I = 9 To WS_Count
Sheets(I).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C19:C114"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("C19:C114").Select
Next I
```

Comment: You have to select any range first then have to apply autofill. You can't autofill by just selecting a sheet.

Comment: @harun24hr could you post this comment as an answer so that I can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you sheet names are exactly as `Sheet(I)` It shows I is a just number. So your sheet names are number?

```
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer

  WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
  For I = 9 To WS_Count
    Sheets(I).Select
     Range("C19:C20").Select
      Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C19:C114"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("C19:C114").Select
 Next I
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this which doesn't need to Select anything. It also eliminates screen flicker and is faster.

```
Sub AutoFillC()
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    For I = 9 To WS_Count
        Sheets(I).Range("C19:C20").AutoFill _
            Destination:=Range("C19:C114"), Type:=xlFillDefault
'        Range("C19:C114").Select **There is rarely need to _
            use the .Select method!
    Next I
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

@harun24hr There is rarely a need to Select any Range on a Sheet.  For simple commands like the OP, specify the Range and the Method you want to apply to it.  If you have multiple Methods to perform on the Range, use a structure like this.  Note the periods "." before each Method

`With Range 
    '.Method
    '.Method1
End With`

Selecting ranges slows your code down, particularly if you haven't disabled ScreenUpdating.